# Serde: How to transform case conditionally?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I need to convert case from keys of json data while processing just the fields I need (I just need some parts of the json data). The conversion of case will be from snake to camel and vice versa.

I tried to do the following:

Let's suppose that we have this struct and that I derive the necessary serde traits:

```
struct ParentSnakeToCamel {
    first_data: A,
    second_data: B,
}

struct ParentCamelToSnake {
    first_data: A,
    second_data: B,
}

struct A {
    field_one: String,
    field_two: Option<u32>,
}

struct B {
    field_three: Option<bool>,
    field_four: String,
}
```

I tried to apply the rename_all attribute of serde to see if it spreads to the inner structs:

```
#[serde(rename_all(deserialize = "snake_case", serialize = "camelCase"]
struct ParentSnakeToCamel {...}

#[serde(rename_all(deserialize = "camelCase", serialize = "snake_case"]
struct ParentCamelToSnake {...}
```

So, whenever I need to parse a json from snake to camel I would use ParentSnakeToCamel struct and if I need to parse from camel to case I would use ParentCamelToSnake.

But rename_all doesn't spread to the inner structs.

What could I do? The only way I see to accomplish that is to duplicate the inner structs to be able to apply rename_all to the inner structs fields according to the case I need to parse. In other words, to create something like ACamel, BCamel, ASnake, BSnake and link to its correspondent parent struct. I believe that's an ugly hack :(

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Am I correct to assume from those names that the only point of all those types is to transform JSON to JSON?

Comment: @mcarton yes and no. I'm doing more things to those types, but in essence I'm transforming JSON to JSON with those types.